# how to make a div horizontally centered

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="1"></div>
   <div class="2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
            width:100%;
        height:351px;
        border:1px solid;
          }
.1{
position:absolute;
width:auto;/*----flexible div--*/
height:351px;
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
  }

.2{
    position:relative;
width:200px;/*---fixed width--*/
margin:0 auto;
/*verti cent*/
margin-top:20% !important;
/*----------*/
padding:8px 0px;
background-color:#212121;
color:whitesmoke;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:500;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
   }
```

The above code states that there is a container div with two child divs. The container div has a width of 100%. The inner two divs are positioned one on top of the other.

My problem: the div2 centers horizontally because it has a fixed width but the div1 cannot be given a fixed div because it needs to be flexible.

Comment: Both of these seem to be left-aligned when the code is put into a jsfiddle.

Comment: There seems to be few things wrong with this, I would recommend putting it in jsfiddle and we can work on it.

Comment: @Roko that is amazing, you were so helpful. If you don't have anything valuable to say its better not to say anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to achieve this with translate trick:

```
.one {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Support: IE9+.

I also changed class names as numeric are not valid.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/77Rac/

Answer (score 1):

First: class names with only numbers is not valid.

Second: you can center an element using two solutions.

Solution 1:
Element is an Block-Element, has a width and horizontally auto on margin like:

```
.myElement {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

Solution 2:
Element is absolute or fixed positioned with a special width:

```
.myElement {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -150px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have modified the above little bit to get the required output.The html and css used are given and the jsfiddle link is also given.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="1">fds</div>
   <div class="2">ffd</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
            width:100%;
        height:351px;
        border:1px solid;
    text-align:center ;
          }
.1{
position:absolute;
width:auto;/*----flexible div--*/
height:351px;
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;

  }

.2{
    position:relative;
width:200px;/*---fixed width--*/
margin:0 auto;
/*verti cent*/
margin-top:20% !important;
/*----------*/
padding:8px 0px;
background-color:#212121;
color:whitesmoke;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:500;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6j7CX/